# Open modal like a Alert

Tags: angular

I want to open a modal like it was a alert() how could I do this?
I created the following modal

```
<ng-template #warningModal>
  <div class="modal-body text-center">
    <p>{{ msg }}</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="decline()" >close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

ts

```
      openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, {class: 'modal-sm'});
  }
```

I know that in html I only need to call the openModal function passing the warningModal but how would I do this in Typescript only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare

```
@ViewChild('warningModal') warningModal: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and

```
this.openModal(this.warningModal);
```